# How to calculate average of x and y coordinates by key in an rdd?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an rdd in a key-value pair form, with a centroid as the key and all the nearest points to them as the values within a list.

```
data = [('d1',
  [(4.832, 1.963),
   (5.439, 2.147),
   (5.009, 2.522)]),
('d2',
  [(4.26, 2.033),
   (5.24, 1.642),
   (4.814, 2.033)]),
('d3',
  [(4.646, 1.827),
   (5.137, 1.858),
   (5.288, 1.842)])]
```

I am trying to calculate the average of all x and y coordinates separately for each centroid by key. I am looking to generate the output as below

```
[('d1',(5.09, 2.21)),
('d2',(4.77, 1.9)),
('d3',(5.02, 1.84))]
```

I have tried the following code but i am not getting any result.

```
data.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: mean(x[1],y[1])).collect()
```

I am kinda stuck here and would really appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reduce by key because the data is already grouped by key. You just need to calculate the mean for each entry, using `numpy.mean` for example.

```
import numpy as np

avg_data = data.map(lambda r: (r[0], tuple(np.mean(r[1], axis=0))))

avg_data.collect()
# [('d1', (5.093333333333334, 2.2106666666666666)), 
#  ('d2', (4.771333333333334, 1.9026666666666667)), 
#  ('d3', (5.023666666666666, 1.8423333333333334))]
```